# Firebase для онлайн игры на Android

Tags: android, firebase

Здравствуйте, вопрос состоит в том, что стоит ли/возможно использовать Firebase для онлайн игры на андроид. Я новичок обессудьте за возможную глупость.
То есть возможно ли использовать Firebase вместо сервера. И как можно там прописать серверную часть?

Comment: Не для любой, а про "как прописать" есть немаленькая документация к Firebase.

Comment: Если точнее может ли она быть заменой PHP+Sql связки для текстовой мморпг (типо: "БК" или "Мир Теней") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно `НЕТ`. Firebase предназначен для простых приложений, web сайтов.
Всё построено на вводе и выводе информации, также `есть серверная обработка, но для игр она не подходит!` Удачи)